# How to correctly format body of POST request

Tags: r, rest, httr

I am adding a page to a website through REST API. I use the following in bash and it works. It creates a new page with the specified title and body content.

```
token="dfrer4e"
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    https://api/pages \
    -d wiki_page[title]=New title \
    -d wiki_page[body]=New content
```

I am trying to do the same using R package `httr`.

```
library(httr)
set_config(add_headers("Authorization"=paste0("Bearer dfrer4e")))
```

This works when I just use the title. It creates a new page with the specified title.

```
POST(url="https://api/pages/",body="wiki_page[title]=New title")
```

but I am not sure how to include the body part as well.

**Attempts:**

I tried providing the body as a vector, but it doesn't work correctly. It combines both into the title. The body remains empty.

```
POST(url="https://api/pages/",body=c("wiki_page[title]=New page","wiki_page[body]=New content"))
```

I tried providing the body as a list, but it returns an error.

```
POST(url="https://api/pages/",body=list("wiki_page"=list("title"="New title","body"="New content")))
Error in curl::handle_setform(handle, .list = req$fields) : 
  Unsupported value type for form field 'wiki_page'.
```

I tried to provide the body as JSON, but it returns a status 400 error.

```
j <- jsonlite::toJSON(list("wiki_page"=list("title"="New title","body"="New content")))
POST(url="https://api/pages/",body=j,encode="json")
```

Unfortunately, I cannot create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to translate that command to `httr` is

```
POST(url="https://api/pages/", 
   body=list(
     "wiki_page[title]" = "New page", 
     "wiki_page[body]" = "New content")
)
```

You need to separate the names and the values in your body so the values can be properly encoded.